# Get same tags with different content from xml with beautifulsoup

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup, tags

I've got this xml:

```
<dc:type>image fixe</dc:type>
<dc:type>image</dc:type>
<dc:type>still image</dc:type>
<dc:type>dessin</dc:type>
<dc:type>drawing</dc:type>
```

I want all the text of all the "dc:type" tags. I can get just the first with `soup.find("dc:type").get_text()` but when I try, e.g.:

```
for i in soup.find_all("dc:type"):
     type = "|".join(i.get_text())
```

it gets me nothing. Also printing just `soup.find_all("dc:type")` gets nothing, while printing just with find seems ok.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working with you.I have got all values.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<dc:type>image fixe</dc:type>
<dc:type>image</dc:type>
<dc:type>still image</dc:type>
<dc:type>dessin</dc:type>
<dc:type>drawing</dc:type>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('dc:type'):
 print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
image fixe
image
still image
dessin
drawing
```

You can use lambda as well to search tag name.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<dc:type>image fixe</dc:type>
<dc:type>image</dc:type>
<dc:type>still image</dc:type>
<dc:type>dessin</dc:type>
<dc:type>drawing</dc:type>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name=='dc:type'):
 print(item.text)
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't, me neither. It's kinda frustrating. But with lambda works, so thanks!